# TypeError: string indices must be integers from iterating through nested dictionaries

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am trying to pull some configuration information out of a json api response. It does loop through parent keys, but will not retrieve values nested beneath them.

I have tried iterating through it by

The JSON response looks like this:

```
{
    "Id": null,
    "result": {
        "methodName": {
            "config_1": {
                "x": "asdf",
                "y": "sdfg"
            }
            "config_2": {
                "1": {
                    "a": "qwer",
                    "b": "wert",
                    "c": {
                        "x": "xxxx",
                        "y": "zzzz"
                }
                "2": {
                    "a": "qwer",
                    "b": "wert",
                    "c": {
                        "x": "xxxx",
                        "y": "zzzz"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My code looks like this:

```py
def get_hardware_config(*args):

    my_url = f"""<url>"""

    try:
        print(f"Retrieving configuration information for hardware")
        api_method = f"<methodName>"
        out = api_get(
            my_url=my_url, name=api_method, my_user=<username>, my_pass=<password>
        )
        for item in out["result"]["methodName"]["config_2"]:
            config_id = item
            print(f"{config_id}")
            serial = item["b"]
            print(f"{identification}")
            chassis_type = item["c"]["x"]
            print(f"{chassis_type}")
            model = item["c"]["y"]
            print(f"{model}")

    except (SystemExit, KeyboardInterrupt):
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"Exception occured")
        return []

get_hardware_config(hardware_name, ip)
```

if i print out only item it works fine

```
1
2
```

but when i go deeper below item it get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./my_script.py", line 160, in get_hardware_config
    serial = item["b"]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Please help

Comment: item is a string and not a dictionary

Comment: @DSC replacing item with 'key' also doesnt fix it or is it that irregardless of what i put in the for loop it views it as a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your loop, `item` is just the dictionary key, i.e. `"1"` or `"2"`.

But what you really want is the *value* of that key.  Try this:

```
for config_id in out["result"]["methodName"]["config_2"]:
    item = out["result"]["methodName"]["config_2"][config_id]
    serial = item["b"]
```

Comment: in your example, for each key i grab the whole set of dictionary key/values underneath, shouldn't the key pass through to the serial variable?